# Limit shellinabox users to specific accounts

Tags: ssh, security, apache-httpd, password, authentication

**Setup and target**

I am running a server with `ssh` and `shellinabox` and would like to restrict login via  `shellinabox` to one specific user only.

**Reasoning and approach**

For security reasons, the main user `main_acc` has certificate-based `ssh` access only (when directly using `ssh` and outside of LAN IP range). I can confirm that password access does not work when accessing from internet via `ssh` command.

In the `shellinabox` usage case, login must be done via password as this is specifically for cases where I do not have my PC with the private keys available. The idea is to add a layer of security by using a "proxy" user `shiabox_acc` that has a resticted shell with the only allowed command being `ssh`ing to `main_acc` on localhost. That way I would have two layers of passwords and two layers where I can use `fail2ban` giving brute force attackers a hard time.

So what I did is

1. in `sshd_config`

- user `main_acc` has no password authentication in general
- `main_acc` has password authentication allowed from LAN-IP range and port 22 (for local maintenance reasons)
- user `shiabox_acc` has password authentication allowed from localhost on port 1011 (the shellinabox port)

2. in the `apache` site setting

- A revese proxy forwards access to the ssh-loaction of my website to the `shellinabox` port

3. on the router firewall settings

- port 1011 is not accessible from WAN
- ports 22, and 443 are open

Now here is the problem:

**Login to `main_acc` via `shellinabox` and password is still possible.**

**Why? How to restrict access to `shiabox_acc` only?**

In my understanding apache receives a website-based request on port 443 and forwards it on localhost to port 1011. Then `ssh` rules should be matching the access port to 1011 and thus not allow password authentication for `main_acc`.

Where am I wrong?

PS: I am aware of the option using `apache` for authentication but would rather understand why my approach fails.

---

Settings in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
#Global:
#DenyUsers
AllowUsers main_acc
PasswordAuthentication no

#shellinabox access
Match LocalPort 1011 User shiabox_acc
        PasswordAuthentication yes
        PubkeyAuthentication no

#LAN access w/ password
Match Address <LAN-IP>,127.0.0.1,::1 LocalPort 22 User main_acc
        PasswordAuthentication yes
        PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Settings in `apache` site:

```
<Location /shellinabox>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:1011/
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

`shellinabox` settings:

```
SHELLINABOX_PORT=1011
SHELLINABOX_ARGS="--no-beep --localhost-only --disable-ssl"
```

**Versions**

- Apache/2.4.57
- ShellInABox version 2.20
- OS: Raspbian 12

Comment: `shellinabox` does *not* use `ssh`, it just shows a regular TTY as a webpage. So whatever you do to `sshd` will not have any effect. Also, disabling SSL is not a good idea as you will be transmitting your keystrokes (including the password) in clear text.

Comment: Well that explains. SSL is handled by receiving in apache on 443. I strongly assume the internal redirection to localhost wont leak?

Comment: Oh I didn't see that. Yes, you are correct, that's a basic reverse proxy and should not compromise security :) (You could up the security a little more by additionally requiring basic auth through apache, just to have 2 layers)